# dispatchEvent from react js component

Tags: reactjs, dispatchevent

I try to dispatch an event within a react component but It throw me this error:
"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched"

My global event:

```
var event = new Event('myevent');

window.addEventListener('myevent', () => {
    console.log("test");
})
```

And from my react component I want to fire it:

```
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the `event` you dispatch inside the component?